# How to return reactor who doesnt have spesicific role

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Hello so I wanted to make my giveaway cannot be entered, unless he has the requirement role

here's my code

```
const filter = (reaction) => {
    reaction.emoji.name === ''
};
let collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, {time: ms(giveawayDuration)});

collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === '' && !reaction.member.roles.cache.has(`${roleRequirement}`)) {
        console.log('he is not in')
        reaction.users.remove()
    }
})
```

I don't know why, but it doesnt remove the user's react, how do I change that

Comment: Does an error appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter is a function that should return a `boolean` or `Promise<boolean>` which in this case isn't returning anything, so probably isn't collecting any message either. (maybe you confused the brackets, you should be using in this scenario `()` instead of `{}` to specify return, or use any)

Anyway, as you want to delete any reaction that isn't :tada: you might as well just return true to collect every reaction.

There is no such object as `MessageReaction.members`. You will have to get the GuildMember by other means. Like:

```
const member = message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id);
```

Your final command may look like this:

```js
const filter = reaction => true;
const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: duration });

collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
  const member = message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id);

  if(reaction.emoji.name !== '' || !member.roles.cache.has(`roleId`)) {
    reaction.users.remove(user);
  }
});
```

If I misunderstood you and you want to keep the reactions other than :tada: and filters only those in which the member isn't in the role, change the filter and remove the verification if it's :tada: in the if statement as it becomes not necessary:

```js
// filter become this
const filter = reaction => reaction.emoji.name === '';

// there's no need for the :tada: if anymore
if(!member.roles.cache.has(`roleId`)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

`member` is not a property of [`MessageReaction`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction). Instead, use the [`Guild.member()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=member) function, and pass the `user` parameter as an argument.

```js
if (
 !message.guild.member(user).roles.cache.has(roleRequirement)
) // I removed the emote verification, as it is already included in the filter
```

---

Also, by emitting the `user` parameter in `reaction.users.remove()`, the argument defaults to `this.reaction.message.client.user`, which I don't think is what you want. Instead, pass the `user.id` property.

```js
reaction.users.remove(user.id)
```

---

Another problem might be with the `roleRequirement` variable. Since you are using [`Collection.has()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=has), make sure `roleRequirement` is the **role ID**, *not* the role object.